# How call method from __new__ constructor in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to `call get_driver_path` inside `__new__` method, and I get this error when I try to run the full code:

```
TypeError: unbound method get_chrome_driver() must be called with
WebBrowserManager instance as first argument (got str instance instead
```

Here is the code:

```
def __new__(self, driver = 'firefox'):
    if not self._instance:
        self._instance = super(WebBrowserManager, self).__new__(self)
        self._profile.native_events_enabled = True
        self.data = {}
        self._system = platform.system()
        if self._local:
            if driver == 'firefox':
                self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(self._profile)
            elif driver == 'chrome':
                self.browser = self.get_chrome_driver(self._system, driver)
            elif driver == 'ie':
                assert self._system == 'Windows', 'Tests on Internet Explorer are only supported on Windows'
                self.browser = webdriver.Ie(self.get_driver_path(driver))
    return self._instance

def get_driver_path(self, driver):
    driver_name = ''
    if driver == 'ie':
        driver_name = 'IEDriverServer.exe'
    elif driver == 'chrome':
       driver_name = 'chromedriver.exe'
    driver_path = "selenium_drivers\\" + driver_name 
    os.environ["webdriver." + driver + ".driver"] = driver_path
    return driver_path
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you made it an instance method, you would need to call it on the instance you created in the `__new__` method (which is static; e.g. not bound to an instance or a class):

```
self.browser = webdriver.Ie(self._instance.get_driver_path(driver))
```

You could make that method static or a class method instead, at which point you can use it via the first argument to `__new__` (which is the class, not an instance; usually you don't use the name `self` but `cls` instead):

```
@staticmethod
def get_driver_path(driver):
```

Note that a `staticmethod` then doesn't take a `self` argument, but your `get_driver_path()` implementation doesn't use that anyway.